# Mobile.css override default.css

Tags: css, mobile, css-specificity

I have a website with just one stylesheet: default.css

I'm manually upgrading it to responsive.

Inside default.css I'm importing the another css file:

```
 @import "mobile.css";
```

---

Ok,

I'm using "**media all**" to check changes at PC's browser.

---

My question is about overriding rules:

For example:

**default.css:**

```
.wrapper .header .logo { width:800px; background-color: black; font-size: 26px; }
```

**mobile.css**

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
    .wrapper .header .logo { width:100%; background-color: blue; font-size: 14px; }
}
```

Usually in a resolution less than 480px the rules especified at mobile.css should work properly.

But seems the default.css is overriding my mobile.css

Assuming that ".wrapper .header .logo" is equivalent to:

0 0 3 0

0 0 3 0

Shouldn't the @media all and (max-width:480px) the main and active CSS?

Comment: Are you making sure the imported styles are loading AFTER your default styles?

Comment: I was importing before because I have also "reset.css" Turns out when I try to import "mobile.css" after my default styles, the command "@import" isn't working :/

Answer (score 1):

Media-queries do not add to the specificity of the selector in your CSS. So if the `@media` declaration comes before the other declaration (default) it will be overriden by the default, because subsequent (in the cascade) delcarations override previous declarations of equal specificity.

So either

1) Instead of using `@import` (which must go at the top of a style-sheet) link to the media-query stylesheet using a `<link>` tag directly in the `<head>`, *after* the default style sheet link. (Also note: `@import` is [bad for performance](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/))

2) somehow increase the [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) of the selector in the media-query

or

3) (last resort -- [use with caution](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)) add `!important` to the style declarations in the media-query.

Answer (score -1):

Use "**!important**" with the properties which you dont want to be overridden.

Ex.

```
.wrapper .header .logo { width:800px; background-color: black !important ; font-size: 26px; }
```